# OpenAI API error: "TypeError: Configuration is not a constructor"

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I am using Node.js with Express.js, and I would like to generate images by taking text from the user. For the moment, I am using the OpenAI API as follows:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> const configuration = new Configuration({ ^
>
> TypeError: Configuration is not a constructor

Answer (score 0):

**You're trying to do initialization incorrectly.**

What you're trying to use worked with the OpenAI Node.js SDK <`v4`, but you have >=`v4`.

The following is the correct initialization if you're using >=`v4`:

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env['OPENAI_API_KEY'],
});
```